# How to get custom attributes from product collection

Tags: magento2

I want to get my custom attributes (Exclude From New and Custom Sale) from my product collection, is that possible?
[image]

should i add more filter from this code?

```
$categoryId = 41; # your ID here
    $productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $categoryId])
    ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['gteq' =>$this->CreatedAt()]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes you can add multiple filter :-**

```
$categoryId = 41; # your ID here
    $productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $categoryId])
    ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['gteq' =>$this->CreatedAt()])
    ->addFieldToFilter('your_attribute_code',['eq' => 'value']); //you can add multiple filter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$categoryId = 41; # your ID here
    $productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $categoryId])
    ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['gteq' =>$this->CreatedAt()]);
    foreach($productCollection as $product) {
        echo $product->getData('exclude_from_new');
        echo $product->getData('custom_sale');
    }
```

Use $product->getData('attribute_code')!

Comment: don't use object manager

Comment: Yes don't use the object manager inside a class

Answer (score 0):

try below code - **Apply filter and get custom attribute value**

```
protected $_productsCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productsCollectionFactory,
    ) {
        $this->_productsCollectionFactory = $productsCollectionFactory;
    }


    $productsCollection = $this->_productsCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection = $productsCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('your_attribute_code', 'value');
    
    foreach ($collection as $_product) {
        if (is_object($_product)) {
            echo $_product->getSku();
            echo $_product->getCustomAttribute();
        }
    }
```